# Youtube IFrame API onError fires with error code 150 for videos from Vevo

Tags: youtube-api

Let me explain my scenario. I want to use [Youtube IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to embed some videos on my website.
I tested the video with id **wdGZBRAwW74** (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdGZBRAwW74) on this page: [Youtube IFrame Player Demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo). And it works OK.

I try this example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'wdGZBRAwW74',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        'onError': onPlayerError
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }

  function onPlayerError(event){
     console.log(event.data);
  }

  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

with some virtual host domains on my localhost and i got result:

1. with domain **app.centaur.com**/youtube/index.htm: IFrame API work OK, the video play without problems.
2. with domain **app.music.com**/youtube/index.html: IFrame API work OK, but the video can not play, API fires onError with error 150 and the embedded player show message "*This video contains content from VEVO, who has blocked it from display on this website. Watch on Youtube*"
3. with domain **app.musiccentaur.com**/youtube/index.htm: like first case, everything work ok
4. with domain **app.centaurmusic.com**/youtube/: like first case, everything work ok

As i know error 150 stand for "The owner of the requested video does not allow it to be played in embedded players". But i see it still work in case 1, 3, 4, so what is it mean ?

Seem all of videos by Vevo related to this problems. I'm not sure if Vevo defined some policy for embedding their videos.

Maybe the problem come from my domain **music.com**, but i'm not sure there is some rules of domain to embed Vevo's video on websites.

What if i buy a domain for my website then i got error 150, this is so bad. :(

Is there anyone deal with this before? Please give me some solutions. Thanks in advance.

Note: this error only occurs on Vevo's videos.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to reverse-engineer Vevo's embedding policy. Even if you do, there's no guarantee your new domain won't get blacklisted later as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content owners are allowed to set up a white/black list of domain names on which embedding is allowed/denied. There is no way to work around these restriction.

This blog post has a bit more info about content restrictions in general: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html

Comment: thank you Jeff! very useful info, now i know exactly what i have to do with this issue, filter those restricted videos or find another solution

Comment: Blog post has been moved to https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions_28.html