# Inconsistent results from Youtube Data API and getting 150 error code while playing video with Iframe api

Tags: youtube-api

This question was posted before. However, I am getting inconsistent results.

I am using the youtube data api v3 and getting some strange results.

I am initially getting a list of videos with the following query:
search?`part=snippet&safeSearch=strict&type=video&videoDefinition=high&videoEmbeddable=true&videoSyndicated=true&fields=items(id,snippet)&q='horses riding gopro'`

Then I individually query each video:

```
videos?part=snippet,statistics,contentDetails,status&id=LUThBDjQocU
```

After that, I am getting the following status information:

```
status: { uploadStatus: "processed", privacyStatus: "public", license: "youtube", embeddable: true, publicStatsViewable: true }
```

Playing the same video with youtube iframe api on a mac:
I am receiving the error code **150**

while on a linux workstation:
I am not getting an error.

Any hints on how to detect the error code 150 during a query to youtube data api?

Comment: Were you be able to check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640757/youtube-iframe-api-onerror-fires-with-error-code-150-for-videos-from-vevo)? Could it be that the content owner restricted the video?

Comment: The post mentioned makes sense. However, the solution presented relates to use of Youtube Data API v2 and the current version is v3. Retrieving information related to a blocked domain is not clear using v3, if available.

Any hints on using Youtube Data v3 to retrieved blocked domains?